# scope of the parameter in dynamic function call

Tags: javascript

In my javascript file im making dynamic call to a common function(more than one time) with different parameter value.

following is the code. edit question is the function and question id is the value return from database it will be different for each question. but once i created this im not getting the correct parameter value. edit question function contain the latest questionId for all the call.

```
questionHTML = <div class="surveyQuestionBlock questionBorder" ><div  class="questionOpts"><ul >'
 +'<li><a onclick="editQuestion(questionId)">'
 +'Edit Question </a></li>'
 questionHTML.show();
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show a complete code snippet?  Hint: indent all your code 4 spaces and it will show as code.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
questionHTML = 
    '<div class="surveyQuestionBlock questionBorder">' +
      '<div class="questionOpts">' + 
        '<ul>' +
          '<li>' +
            '<a onclick="editQuestion(\'' + questionId + '\')">' +
              'Edit Question' + 
            '</a>' +
          '</li>' +
        '</ul>' +
      '</div>' +
    '</div>';
```

In other words, evaluating the *current* value of `questionId` and place it directly in the function call.

Comment: In this \'' + questionId + '\' , \' is to close the quotes can you please explain this

Comment: I was assuming that `questionId` is a `String`.  If so, then it also needs to be in quotes.  So I used `\'` to escape the single quote so it didn't close the JavaScript string.  If `questionId` is not a `String`, the `\'`s can be removed.